# Extjs 4 Basic(can not load chart)

Tags: extjs4

I am just learning ExtJs-4.

I am stuck to create chart bar on the panel.

It's just same code from official Ext website.

This is my panel that has the code to create the chart, model, and store.

```
    Ext.define("park.view.mainPanel",{
    extend:'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.mainPanel',
    title: 'edit User',
            initComponent: function(){
        Ext.define('WeatherPoint', {
            extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
            fields: ['temperature', 'date']
        });

        var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
            model: 'WeatherPoint',
            data: [
                { temperature: 58, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 8) },
                { temperature: 63, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 9) },
                { temperature: 73, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 10) },
                { temperature: 78, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 11) },
                { temperature: 81, date: new Date(2011, 1, 1, 12) }
            ]
        });

         var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {


           store: store,
            theme: 'Category1',
        });


        this.callParent(arguments);

    }


});
```

It should be really easy if someone knows it.
But hard to fix it to noobie like me.

Answer (score 0):

You should add `chart` as your panel child. Try adding `this.items = [chart];` before `this.callParent(arguments);`

Answer (score 0):

You are missing chart axes and series in your chart definition.